# Does anyone know what below message is in linux?

Tags: linux

Does anyone know what we are seeing here in Linux?

sys:$6$U78cZenSGEJaVp.u$AzzxjZZD.UTob6/XHzls70gKBsSDUdC9gmtu1lAKlNGkvAaGTNozDPVnWByf3eQi7LCe2342Y2b.OioJpFvs10:18826:0:

I have tried doing some findings but no luck.

Comment: Looks like a line from `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you so much, I have verified it. it was a line from /etc/shadow

Comment: user = sys, sha-512 password hash, password last changed July 18, 2021

Comment: Thank you @stark, I have tried decoding it using john so confirmed.